# can not install kvm on my ubuntu

Tags: kvm-virtualization

i have a ubuntu desktop 12.04 64bit on vmware.
with vmware i already turn on VT-x ( my CPU is intel).
Now i want to install kvm on this ubuntu virtual machine.

### 1. type:

> egrep -c ‘(svm|vmx)’ /proc/cpuinfo

the ubuntu answer : 1

### 2. install kvm:

> sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin bridge-utils virt-manager

-->> 0K

### 3. type

> adduser localadmin libvirtd

--> the user already in libvird

### 4. log out and log in

### 5.

> virsh -c qemu:///system list

but i get the error:

> error: Cannot read CA certificate '/etc/pki/CA/cacert.pem': No such
>   file or directory error: failed to connect to the hypervisor

### 6.change to root account and try again

> virsh -c qemu:///system list

then nothing happen.it's hang. i try to open virutal manager but it said no connection so
anyone can help me ?
[máy thủy bình](http://tracdiaminhquan.com/may-thuy-binh-1.html) , [máy cân bằng laser](http://tracdiaminhquan.com/thiet-bi-can-bang-tu-dong-bang-tia-lazer-1.html) chính hãng.